# Twice job results in sql server, last one is left in progress

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have the job **MP - Create CSV** which execute a package SSIS in sql server 2008, when I check for the job history I see the result at step 0, I expand and I have 2 results for the step 1.
Fist result have the icon for **Success** with the result :

> Message
>   Executed as user: companyname\sa. The step succeeded.

The second one have the step 1 also, but with the icon for **In Progress** with the result :

> Message
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  11:50:00 PM
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
>   Started:  11:50:00 PM
>   Finished: 11:50:26 PM
>   Elapsed:  26.645 seconds

My problem is I have a report to show all the job with their status not equal to 1 (success), my report do not work anymore because of this result "In progress".

My questions are why do I have 2 results for my step ? I think I should have only one. And what should I do when I have a job with a step status left "In progress" ?

For more information, my job is running daily and succeed every time, thank you.
User Josien have suggested me to ask my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990485/twice-job-results-in-sql-server-last-one-is-left-in-progress#comment21054398_14990485) here.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate because my first question was migrate from stackexchange to dba.stackexchange, I do not know how to remove this post.

Comment: Don't worry, a moderator will merge the 2 questions.